# Type of a heterogeneous list (HList) of values behind a type constructor

Tags: haskell, types, data-kinds

I want to define a function that takes an arbitrarily sized [HList](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HList-0.5.0.0) of values behind some type constructor, e.g. `Maybe`:

```hs
foo :: HList '[t a, t b, t c, ...] -> Bar
-- For example:
foo :: HList '[Maybe a, Maybe b, Maybe c, ...] -> Bar
```

Is there some way to do that in Haskell? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a constraint using a custom type class, requiring the types to involve the same `f` type constructor.

```
import Data.HList.HList

class HSame (t :: [Type]) where

instance HSame '[] where
instance HSame '[f x] where
instance HSame (f u : xs) => HSame (f t ': f u ': xs) where

foo :: HSame xs => HList xs -> Bool
foo _ = True
```

Alternatively, define a `Map f xs` type family and define

```
foo :: HList (Map f xs) -> Bool
foo _ = True
```

but this won't work well with type inference, since there's no easy way for the compiler to infer `f` and `xs`.

Answer (score 2):

The [`NP`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sop-core-0.5.0.1/docs/Data-SOP-NP.html#t:NP) type from [sop-core](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sop-core-0.5.0.1) is an n-ary product of kind `(k -> Type) -> [k] -> Type` parameterized by a type-level list `[k]` and a type constructor `(k -> Type)` which wraps each term-level component:

```
Prelude> :set -XDataKinds
Prelude> import Data.SOP.NP
Prelude Data.SOP.NP> :t Just True :* Nothing :* Nil
Just True :* Nothing :* Nil :: NP Maybe '[Bool, x]
```